# How to capture the output with syslog library

Tags: python, logging, syslog

I have a syslog file and I need to read this file and save the information in a variable. I'm using a loop to read the file and get the information that I want.

```
for line in set(open(ROUTER_LIST)):
    router_name = line.split("=")[1].strip()
```

I would like to know if there is any possibility to use the logging library to read the file?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this is not possible.

The Python `logging` module is, according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/logging.html), an event logging system, not a log file parser or reader. It is designed for generating output, not serving as an input channel.